# How to remove gap between ListViewItems in Win7

Tags: wpf, listview, windows-7, windows-xp

I developed a WPF application under WinXP and my ListView had my expected layout. After starting the same software under Win7, I saw that the ListViewItems have a small gap between each row.
I played with Margin und Padding for each element, but I can’t find a solution where the layout is the same under WinXP and Win7 without writing individual code.
I assume that it has something to do with the current Windows theme, but I can’t catch it. Does some have a hint?

Screenshot WindowsXP
[image: Layout XP]

Screenshot Windows 7
[image: Layout 7]

Here is some (simplified) XAML that I use

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CellBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-6,0,-6,0"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
            <Border Name="NameBorder" Style="{StaticResource CellBorderStyle}">
                <TextBlock>MyName</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddressTemplate">
            <Border Name="AddressBorder" Style="{StaticResource CellBorderStyle}" Background="LightSteelBlue">
                <TextBlock>MyAddress</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StreetTemplate">
            <Border Name="StreetBorder" Style="{StaticResource CellBorderStyle}" Background="LightGreen">
                <TextBlock>MyStreet</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CityTemplate">
            <Border Name="CityBorder" Style="{StaticResource CellBorderStyle}">
                <TextBlock>MyCity</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" x:Name="colName"
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address" x:Name="colAddress" 
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource AddressTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Street" x:Name="colStreet" 
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource StreetTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="City" x:Name="colCity" 
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource CityTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I can't answer you question directly but can recommend the WPF spy utility Snoop. You can analyze each element of your application and change its properties instantly while the application is running. Maybe you can find a way to change the properties to let your list items look like you want them to with this tool and then make these changes in your xaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted ControlTemplate using Expression Blend. Modified BorderThickness in Style of ListViewItem to 0.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#8E6EA6F5" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF1FBFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD5F1FE" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F4FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF9BDDFB" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedInactiveFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEDED" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEAF9FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC9EDFD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#75FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCCF0FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#80FFFFFF"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedInactiveFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFCFCF"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedHoverFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/> did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the border top and bottom margins as well:

```
enter code here
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-6,0,-6,0"></Setter>
to:
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-6,-3,-6,-3"></Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra space if putting focus on the listview.

It goes away when you use

```
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
```

On the itemcontainerstyle